# Подсказка при вводе данных в текстовое поле React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Всем доброго времени суток, пишу проект на React, хотелось бы добавить подсказку для пользователя о возможных командах, которые будут введены в текстовое поле, так, как это к примеру реализовано в вольфраме.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

Comment: А откуда будут браться возможные варианты команд?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-autosuggest

Comment: @ДенисСтепанов, кажется это то, что нужно, большое спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется что это вопрос не совсем про js с React, точнее частично. Так как тут и клиентская часть и серверная, и больше я сказал бы даже серверная на процентов 90. На js React все просто один input а под ним div в котором блок ответов. При каждом нажатии в input react отправляет ajax запрос на сервер с кусочком введенного слова. А вот серверная часть тут вообще не простая, по приходящим кусочкам должна производиться выборка из чего-то какой то базы данных, и эта выборка возвращается клиенту, ну и обрисовывается в тот самый div под inputom.На https://www.wolframalpha.com/ и на всех поисковиках это работает именно так.Через ajax запрос, ответ.